# Woocommerce Subscriptions get next payment date when subscription is renewed

Tags: hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I’m using Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin in my Woocommerce site. I want to post the new renewal date for a subscription to an external API when a subscription is renewed. I’m trying to use the ‘woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete’ action hook so whenever a subscription is renewed I can access the $subscription object and the $last_order object. But when I try to get the $subscription->get_date(‘nex_payment’) date, it will always return the last renewal date and not the next renewal date. I looks like the $subscription has not really been updated before this hook and the ‘next_payment’ date is still not updated to the next value when firing this action hook.

Does anybody know how to get the real ‘next_payment’ date after a renewal has been completed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those that could be interested in a solution, I've finally found that there's an action hook called 'woocommerce_subscription_date_updated' that fires when a date of the subscription has been updated.

Simply add an action to this hook:

```
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_date_updated', 'subscription_date_update', 10, 3);

function subscription_date_update($subscription, $date_type, $datetime)
{
  //Do your stuff here...
}
```

Comment: `woocommerce_subscription_date_updated ` is not an action but a filter. have you resolved your issue using this? thanks

Comment: its a filter, but you apply action on that filter!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "woocommerce_subscription_date_updated" is an action in woosubscriptions v3 (although not in the API documentation) and was a filter in woosubscriptions v2 that is now depreciated. Since its not in the API documentation, I suppose that means it could change without notice.  It is used internally in woosubscriptions.